# Need to delete above duplicate row of same user in database table

Tags: mysql, cakephp

HI We have plan_users table in which every plan members & its admin record there with a unique plan_id for each plan,but here is the issue like a person is already member of a plan so he is in that table but another plan admin sent invitation to join the same person to join his plan so in this case what we want the person click on mail a action should be there the person should delete from past plan record & join to new plan with new plan_id

we have field `id`,`user_id`, `plan_id`, `email` in `Plan_users` table, So when same person will join both in that case his user_id will same & email will same . So I need how to delete past record of person who has same user_id in table cakephp
One thing we can't stop  user to change his plan ,just we need to remove him past plan.

Comment: Please share the table schema, sample data and what the final result would be.

Answer (score 0):

just check is there any fro taht user in plan_users table. If yes then change the plan id with the new one and if no then simply add new record.

```
$data['PlanUser']['id'] = $this->PlanUser->field('id',array('PlanUser.user_id'=>$userid));
$data['PlanUser']['plan_id'] = $planid;
$data['PlanUser']['user_id'] = $usernid;
$this->PlanUser->save($data);
```

It may help